# gulp-dependents and gulp-changed scss

Tags: css, sass, gulp

Hello I am trying to compile just sass files that changed, my issue is that if I change a parent scss the child didn't changed so gulp-changed doesn't recompile it. I was trying to use gulp-dependent but seems is only for the other way around?

I tried both 
 .pipe(changed(ARGS))
 .pipe(dependents())
and 
 .pipe(dependents())
 .pipe(changed(ARGS))

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply target all your *.scss files instead of just the parent? What is your setup right now ? You could use `gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')`

Comment: thanks, yes I do that but if i just change the parent doesn't seem to be a solution because it compares just the childrens